# git - update a fork hosted on an organization

Tags: github

I have fork-ed a project on an organisation I'm part of. I'm trying to get the fork updated as there were commits (see below) just by using the web interface.

[image]

I've searched the net but I did not find anything relevant.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i've never played with someone's branch before, my question sounds *stupid* but bear in mind : This was my first time.

Please find the way to update the branch you've forked , when that person who own the branch, committed changes and you want your fork to be the same as his branch. All done by Github's web interface

- Go to the pull request tab
- Click on the button **New pull request**
- Create a pull request
- Commit (as you are asking for his changes willingly, you are the one committing :))